# How to create a map of a country that allows me to select its states and take that input

Tags: flutter, user-interface, user-experience

I´m new on Flutter, currently I´m using a `FloatingActionButton` that displays `a dialog` that allows me to select one of the options that I show you `in the image`, this only boils down to using a list of `RadioButtons` and only one of them can be selected, but now what I would look for A better experience is to use **a country map** that allows me **to do exactly the same** thing `(select a state)` but this time by tapping on the state section

I would be grateful if you could tell me **all the possibilities** I have to be able to achieve the above, I found the `CustomPainter` option but in this case due to the specific form of the countries and states I find it quite tedious to do it this way, perhaps there is some other functionality that allows me use an **image of a country** and **section** it internally so that the interaction can be independent or I don't know what other types of solutions can be had in this case.

This is an **image of the dialogue** that I want to replace:
[current dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yHnk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have tackled this same behavior on a client app where we had a map and the user could press a section on the map to trigger a callback function/open a screen.

You can use [flutter_image_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_map) which has a [ROI selection tool](https://github.com/itzMeerkat/flutter_image_map/blob/master/index.html) that is in its repository. Once you've mapped everything just follow the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_map/example) where you will be implementing the onPress callbacks depending on the region.